I need to determine which statistical test and data presentation to use
If I was looking to get 2 users to produce values using a software. These numbers each correlate to a subject. I want to compare the similarity between the numbers each user gets for each subject. I am also looking to compare this data to the qualitative data that is already known. I was wondering what statistical tests I could preform and what data presentation would be best.
This is an example
User 1 gets values 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 For subjects 1-5
User 2 gets values 2, 4, 5, 4 and 2 for subjects 1-5.
it is already known that subject 1, 3 and 3 are positive and 4 and 5 are negative. how can I prove that the values correlate to whether the subject is positive or negative. Thank you
